# ExpressJS sorting schema object in route file

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, express, mongoose

I am looking to sort my database information by the most recent date as the first object followed by older in descending order. Currently my data is in the reverse order and I'm not sure where I should be calling the sort method since I'm not using the `.find` method. I tried

```
`.get(function(req, res, next) {

Blogpost.paginate({}, req.query.page, req.query.limit, {sort: ['dateString', -1]}, function(err, pageCount, blogpost, itemCount) {`
```

but I receive a `TypeError: object is not a function`

Here is my model:

blogModel.js

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;



var BlogPostSchema  = new Schema({
        title: String,
        blogUrl: String,
        author: String,
        tagline: String,
        category: String,
        content: String,
        tags: { type: String, lowercase: true },
        date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
});

BlogPostSchema.post('init', function (post) {
    var date = new Date(post.date || Date.now() );
    post.dateString = date.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();

});

BlogPostSchema.plugin( mongoosePaginate );

var Blogpost = mongoose.model("Blogpost", BlogPostSchema);



module.exports = mongoose.model('Blogpost', BlogPostSchema);
```

routes.js

var express = require('express');

```
var router = express.Router();
var blogDB = require('../config/blogDB.js');
var Blogpost = require('./models/blogModel.js');
var paginate = require('express-paginate');

//index 
router.use(paginate.middleware(10, 50));




    router.route('/') 


        // START GET method
        .get(function(req, res, next) {

            Blogpost.paginate({}, req.query.page, req.query.limit, {sort: ['dateString', -1]}, function(err, pageCount, blogpost, itemCount) {




                if (err) return next(err)

                        if (err)
                            res.send(err);




                        res.format({
                            html: function() {
                                res.render('pages/index', {
                                    blogpost: blogpost,
                                    pageCount: pageCount,
                                    itemCount: itemCount
                                })
                            },
                            json: function() {

                                res.json({
                                    object: 'blogpost',
                                    has_more: paginate.hasNextPages(req)(pageCount),
                                    data: blogpost
                                })
                            }
                        }); // END res.format(html, json)
            }); // END Blogpost.paginate
        }); // END GET method

router.route('/admin/posts/create')

    // START POST method
        .post(function(req, res) {

            console.log("New instance");

            var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model

            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // set the blog title
            blogpost.blogUrl = blogpost.title.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,"-");
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
            blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // set the tagline
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // set the blog content
            blogpost.category = req.body.category; // set the category
            blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; // set the tags
                //Save Blog Post
                blogpost.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.redirect(303, '/'); //NEEDS TO BE CHANGED
                });

        }) // END POST method
```

index.ejs:

```
<div class="blog-content">
                <% blogpost.forEach(function(blogpost) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h2><a href="/blog/<%= blogpost.blogUrl %>" class="blog-title"><%= blogpost.title %></a></h2></td>
                        <td><h3><%= blogpost.dateString %></h3></td>
                        <td><h3 class="blog-category"><%= blogpost.category %></h3></td>
                        <td><h3 class="blog-tagline"><i><%= blogpost.tagline %></i></h3></td>
                        <td><p><%=: blogpost.content | truncate:800 | append:'...' %></p></td>
                        <td><a href="/blog/<%= blogpost.blogUrl %>" class="blog-read-more">Read More</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <% }); %>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used the paginate plugin before, but it would appear that the paginate plugin does a **very non-standard** thing of having the `options` parameter come **after the callback**. :(

It also looks like the there is a problem is with the `sort` property.

The `TypeError: object is not a function` error is happening because the paginate code is trying to call your options hash as a function. https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate/blob/master/lib/mongoose-paginate.js#L54

It should probably be either this:

```
Blogpost.paginate({}, req.query.page, req.query.limit, 
    function(err, pageCount, blogpost, itemCount) {
 ...
}, {sort: {'date': -1 } );
```

or this, as I think mongoose does a non-standard "sortBy" instead of "sort".

```
Blogpost.paginate({}, req.query.page, req.query.limit, 
     function(err, pageCount, blogpost, itemCount) {
 ...
}, {sortBy: {'date': -1 } );
```

You don't actually want to sort by "dateString" as it isn't really in the database. Sort by "date" and use the dateString for rendering. Also, calling the field "date" is probably sub-optimal as it is used as a keyword in so many places. I'd call it createdDate or somesuch.